# Why doesn't jQuery dialog() method Interrupt JavaScript Processing?

Tags: jquery, dialog

My code does not wait for user to interact with a jQuery dialog before continuing to process the ajax call. Why doesn't it behave like a JavaScript confirm or alert which necessitate pushing a button in order so that the client script continues?

```
// droppable: Associate droppable to each account type panel (any element on the page having a CSS class of RoleJar), 
        // and in the drop event of droppable invoke JQuery's ajax function so that it calls the server side page method DropUserIntoRole.
        $('.RoleJar').droppable({
            drop: function (e, ui) {
                var userID = $('#' + draggedObject.id).children('input:hidden')[0].value;

                var accountType = $('#' + this.id).children('input:hidden')[0].value;
                var usersInRole = $('#' + this.id).find('.NamesInRole');

                var userInRole = false;
                for (var i = 0; i < usersInRole.length; i++) {
                    if (usersInRole.children('input:hidden')[i].value == userID) {
                        userInRole = true;
                    }
                }

                var confirmed = false;
                var canEdit = 'false';

                if (userInRole) {
                    alert(userID + ' is already in the ' + accountType + ' Account Type role');

                    confirmDialog = false;
                }
                else {
                    confirmed = confirm('Move ' + userID + ' to the ' + accountType + ' Account Type role?');
                }

                if (confirmed) {
                    $get('" + lblConfirm.ClientID + @"').innerText = 'Grant ' + userID + ' edit privileges?';

                    $('.HiddenPanel').dialog({
                        autoOpen: true,
                        draggable: false,
                        modal: true,
                        resizable: false,
                        title: 'Edit Privileges',
                        buttons: [
                        {
                            text: 'Yes',
                            click: function() {
                                canEdit = 'true';
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'No',
                            click: function() {
                                canEdit = 'false';
                                $(this).dialog('close');
                            }
                        }]
                    });
//Why does the dialog invocation above not prevent the below ajax function from being invoked only once user clicks Yes or No?

                    $.ajax({
                        url: currentPage + '/DropUserIntoRole',
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                        data: '{ userID: \'' + userID + '\', accountType: \'' + accountType + '\', canEdit: \'' + canEdit + '\' }',
                        success: function (result) {
                            var results = result.d.split(',');
                            alert(results[0] + ' ' + results[1] + ' has been added to the ' + results[2] + ' Account Type');
                            window.location = results[3];
                        },
                        failure: function (result) {
                            alert(result.d);
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    confirmDialog = false;
                }

                droppedToAccountType = true;
                priorAccountType = accountType;
            }
        }).addClass('CornerArcs');
```

Comment: _"Why doesn't it behave like a JavaScript confirm or alert?"_ Short answer - because it's a div, not a confirm or alert. Put the ajax call into the dialog's button click callback.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Like this?

Comment: $('.HiddenPanel').dialog({
... close: function(event, ui){
 $.ajax({
 url: currentPage + '/DropUserIntoRole',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
  data: '{ userID: \'' + userID + '\', accountType: \'' + accountType + '\', canEdit: \'' + canEdit + '\' }',
  success: function (result) {
  var results = result.d.split(',');
  alert(results[0] + ' ' + results[1] + ' has been added to the ' + results[2] + ' Account Type');
  window.location = results[3];        },});
       },

Comment: I got it to work by running the ajax function in the click: function() portion of both the 'No' button and 'Yes' button. Thanks!